# Почему файлы не загружаются на сервер

Tags: php, веб-программирование, файлы

```
if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)
{ // Проверяем, загрузил ли пользователь файл
    $destiation_dir = dirname(__FILE__) .'/'.$_FILES['file']['name']; // Директория для размещения файла
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destiation_dir ); // Перемещаем файл в желаемую директорию
}
else
{
echo 'No File Uploaded'; // Оповещаем пользователя о том, что файл не был загружен
}

print_r($_FILES);

<form action="" method="POST" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <input type="text" name="product_name" placeholder="Product name">
                <input type="text" name="product_descr" placeholder="Product description">
                <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price">
                <input type="text" name="product_size" placeholder="Size">
                <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type">
                <input type="submit" name="send">
            </form>
```

Вот такой стандартный код, но он не работает, не понимаю почему. Почитал насчет этого на форумах, вроде все правильно делаю, код рабочий, но файл не получается. В массиве $_FILES, пусто(ARRAY()). укажите на ошибку. Спасибо:)*

Comment: в теге form присутствует enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: да, все это есть

Comment: посмотрел редактированный код, какие-то странные кавычки у enctype

Comment: исправил, проблема была в этом) спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отправки файлов на сервер в header Content-Type должен быть multipart/form-data. Либо, если речь о стандартной форме (), то нужно указать это с помощью атрибута enctype

Comment: enctype есть, все верно по идеи должно быть, но ничего не получается. Впервые делаю это

Comment: А если попробовать вывести var_dump($_FILE) до отправки и после? Можно для начала глянуть, что там вообще происходит